# Is it possible for an almond tree to grow in a tropical country?

Tags: trees, nut-trees

I have been searching in Google, but I got neither information or reference regarding this issue. I'm wondering is it possible for an almond tree to grow in a tropical country such as Indonesia?

If it is not, why? Is there any study to make it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably not, which is why you don't find them in the tropics. Almonds grow well in Mediterranean type climates, with warm dry summers and mild wet winters. They also require a number of hours of chilling to enable the buds to break dormancy, between 300 to 600 hours at a temperature below 7.2 deg. C. Optimum temperatures for growth and nut production are 15-30 deg C, which is somewhat lower than a tropical region.

You could always think about using [Terminalia catappa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminalia_catappa) instead, though it is a large tree at maturity - it's commonly known as the Tropical Almond, but also has lots of other common names. It's a large tree which does produce nut like seeds - the kernel inside is said to be similar in taste to an almond, and is edible when fully ripe.

Answer (score 2):

Almonds have been grown in Nigeria which is also a tropical country.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you explain how you know that almonds are grown in Nigeria? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just give it a try - plants are somewhat adaptable, so it may work. However, I personally think that the Sea Almond (Terminalia cattapa) would provide you not only with almond-like fruits that indeed taste like sweet almonds, but it's also a lovely shade tree, has beautiful timber and gets a maple-like leaf coloration in fall. An alley of these trees lining a driveway looks stunning, and a single tree to shade the backyard garde is perfect. In Australia you can get them eg from Daley's Fruits in Kyogle, but around the world nurseries should be able to get you some.

Here is a photo of Terminalia cattapa:

[Terminalia cattapa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EC4e.jpg)

Happy gardening !!

Answer (score 1):

We have been growing Almonds in the Bahamas (Caribbean) for centuries. Although it is not exported, it is always a delight to eat the tasty fruit around the nut and crack the nut open for the interior delight. Answer is yes!!